# Query to get limited rows of each type

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hello guys I m using CI framework and i have written a query ...as below

```
public function home_lastest_company()
    {
        $this->db->select('c.id as company_id,c.name as company,c.type,cp.company_logo,it.title as industry,jc.title as category');
        $this->db->from(JB_COMPANY_TABLE . ' c');
        $this->db->join(JB_COMPANY_PROFILE_TABLE . ' cp', 'c.id=cp.jb_company_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join(JB_INDUSTRY_TYPE . ' it', 'c.industry_id = it.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join(JB_CATEGORY . ' jc', 'c.category_id = jc.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('c.visibility', '1');
        $this->db->where('c.status', '1');
        $this->db->order_by('c.created_date', 'desc');
        $objquery = $this->db->get();
        return $objquery->result_array();
    }
```

the sql query for this is

```
 SELECT `c`.`id` as company_id, `c`.`name` as company, `c`.`type`, `cp`.`company_logo`, `it`.`title` as industry, `jc`.`title` as category FROM (`jb_company` c)
    LEFT JOIN `jb_company_profile` cp ON `c`.`id`=`cp`.`jb_company_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `jb_industry_type` it ON `c`.`industry_id` = `it`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `jb_category` jc ON `c`.`category_id` = `jc`.`id`
    WHERE `c`.`visibility` = '1' AND `c`.`status` = '1' ORDER BY `c`.`created_date` desc
```

I get an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 14
            [company] => Tech Hive
            [type] => 0
            [company_logo] => clogo8.png
            [industry] => BROADCASTING
            [category] => Electronics
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 13
            [company] => WadeTech
            [type] => 0
            [company_logo] => download.jpg
            [industry] => INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY
            [category] => Information Technology
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 16
            [company] => Reliance
            [type] => 0
            [company_logo] => reliance.jpg
            [industry] => ELECTRONICS
            [category] => Electronics
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 12
            [company] => AVIVA
            [type] => 1
            [company_logo] => aviva.jpg
            [industry] => CONSULTING
            [category] => Management
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 11
            [company] => Apple
            [type] => 2
            [company_logo] => apple10.jpg
            [industry] => Agriculture
            [category] => Information Technology
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 9
            [company] => Samsung
            [type] => 1
            [company_logo] => samsung.jpg
            [industry] => ELECTRONICS
            [category] => Information Technology
        )
 )
```

Actually there are a lot more data then one shown above .... now what i want is a query in which i get data limited according to type feild. for example i want 20 rows of type 0 20 rows of type 1, 20 rows of type 2

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in MySQL, but it is not as simple as adding a LIMIT clause. Here is an article that explains the problem in detail:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

It's a good article - he introduces an elegant but naïve solution to the "Top N per group" problem, and then gradually improves on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

step1: Select type of all the groups using `GROUP BY` command.
For example

```
SELECT type FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY type
```

So now you get all type value  which exists in a table.

Step 2: Then loop your command with LIMIT condition, input as type.

```
SELECT `c`.`id` as company_id, `c`.`name` as company, `c`.`type`, `cp`.`company_logo`, `it`.`title` as industry, `jc`.`title` as category FROM (`jb_company` c)
    LEFT JOIN `jb_company_profile` cp ON `c`.`id`=`cp`.`jb_company_id` AND type=$array[type] 
    LEFT JOIN `jb_industry_type` it ON `c`.`industry_id` = `it`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `jb_category` jc ON `c`.`category_id` = `jc`.`id`
    WHERE `c`.`visibility` = '1' AND `c`.`status` = '1' ORDER BY `c`.`created_date` desc LIMIT 0,20
```

If you want to pagination concept in your site, better try to previous answer in this post.